# Exception Occured while updating cluster data

Tags: gemfire, geode

After implementing SecurityManager over the deprecated AccessControl and Authenticator, I am unable to view the memberDetails when I clicked on the server under topology.  It shows "Connecting .. Member[] is not available Go To Clusterview". 
Cluster View > Data tab doesn't show any regions but under DataBrowser, I am able to access and query my regions.

I am at a loss for what am I suppose to need for the NullPointerException.

Log file:
Exception Occurred while updating cluster data:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
  at org.apache.geode.tools.pulse.internal.data.JMXDataUpdater.initializeMember(JMXDataUpdater.java:1374) ~[classes/:?]
  at org.apache.geode.tools.pulse.internal.data.JMXDataUpdater.updateClusterMember(JMXDataUpdater.java:1415) ~[classes/:?]
  at org.apache.geode.tools.pulse.internal.data.JMXDataUpdater.updateData(JMXDataUpdater.java:323) ~[classes/:?]
  at org.apache.geode.tools.pulse.internal.data.Cluster.updateDate(Cluster.java:2336) ~[classes/:?]
  at org.apache.geode.tools.pulse.internal.data.Cluster.run(Cluster.java:2300) ~[classes/:?]
.

Edit: There's also a lot of "attempting to get session; create = false; session is null = false; session has id = true. Attempting to retrieve session with key org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSession@ac417d3"

Comment: What permissions have you assigned to the user you're logging into Pulse with? They would need at least `CLUSTER:READ` and `DATA:READ` for everything to work in the UI. I think this error may occur if the user does not have the correct permissions.

Comment: Yes the user I am using have both permissions allowed. I also tried removing everything else in the "authorize" method and leaving only "return true;" but it still gives the same issue.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue using the bundled `SimpleSecurityManager`. Do you also have TLS enabled? Are you running Pulse embedded in the locator or in a separate container?

Comment: Yes, I have TLS enabled on the browser and I am running it in embedded mode. I tried running just the SecurityManager class alone and same issue too. Am I just missing a few jar files? Just an update, I realized under ServerGroups and Redundancy Zones, I can see two thin green bars but are located to the furthest left side of the entire middle space. Top is showing what was mentioned in my opening post. Clicking on the bottom one (which is my actual Server but with 0 values and null value for Geode Version) brought me to memberDetails.html where I can see my regions and its entry count, size.

Comment: I think we'd need to see the logs for your locator and server to fully understand what's going on here. Perhaps you should post to user@geode.apache.org.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help!